Target children from parent?
I am aware you can target all children like so:
 <div class="*:underline">
     <a href="#">Click Me</a>
     <span> | </span>
     <a href="#">Click Me</a>
 </div>

But I only wish to target a tags, is there a way to do this (inline)?

Use [&>a]:underline to target a child
Example:
<div class="[&>a]:underline">
https://play.tailwindcss.com/QORnGWaPtZ
